# Using Ubuntu Environment Variable in Replacing a String Using SED

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed, environment-variables

How can an environment variable in ubuntu be used to replace a string using SED?

Currently, I am using:

```
sed -i.bak 's/autoLogoffTime="[^"]*"/autoLogoffTime="2:15,AM"/g' file.xml
```

I would like to be able to have the replacement string as a system environment variable

```
export LOGOFF_TIME="2:15,AM"
sed -i.bak 's/autoLogoffTime="[^"]*"/autoLogoffTime=$LOGOFF_TIME/g' file.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that, within single-quotes, shell variables are not expanded.  For them to be expanded reliably, they should be within double quotes.  Try:

```
sed 's/autoLogoffTime="[^"]*"/autoLogoffTime="'"$LOGOFF_TIME"'"/g' file.xml
```

Notice that we have left the first and last parts of the expression inside single-quotes.  This avoids issues with escaping the `"` within a double-quoted string.

Don't use this method unless the source of the `LOGOFF_TIME` variable is under your control.  If the `LOGOFF_TIME` variable contained sed-active characters, the results could be unwanted.

If you don't control the , then it is safer to use awk:

```
awk -v x="$LOGOFF_TIME" '{gsub(/autoLogoffTime="[^"]*"/, "autoLogoffTime=\"" x "\"")} 1' file.xml
```

To change a file in-place using awk:

```
awk -i inplace -v x="$LOGOFF_TIME" '{gsub(/autoLogoffTime="[^"]*"/, "autoLogoffTime=\"" x "\"")} 1' file.xml
```

Comment: Great solution. Do you see any issue if I pipe `find . -iname file.xml -exec` to either `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  For example: `find . -iname file.xml -exec sed -i.bak 's/autoLogoffTime="[^"]*"/autoLogoffTime="'"$LOGOFF_TIME"'"/g' {} \;`